# Mirror of a local K3 surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mirror-symmetry

Is there any description of a mirror manifold of a (non-compact) Calabi-Yau threefold given by the total space of the trivial line bundle on a K3 surface? If yes, in what way is it a mirror?

Thanks for any references.

Comment: Suppose you know the mirror $X^\vee$ of a K3 surface $X$. Since the mirror of $\mathbb{C}$ is the Landau-Ginzburg model $(\mathbb{C}^\ast,z)$, it follows that the mirror of $X\times\mathbb{C}$ is $(X^\vee\times\mathbb{C}^\ast,z)$, where the superpotential $z$ is given by the coordinate on the second factor.